# How can I set a Tab from Tabcontrol as the last Tab C#

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I have a question how can I make a certain Tab (TabControl) that is every time at the end. Because if I click on the + it get 1 back.

[the tab that should always be at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC4vC.png)

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EFhc.png)

Comment: Is `+` also a `TabPage`? If so, `yourTabControl.TabPages.Insert(yourTabControl.TabCount - 1, "Script 2");`

Comment: @dr.null thx man